# OnExceptionAspect and async methods

Tags: postsharp

I've seen that [PostSharp has now introduced support for async methods](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/New-in-PostSharp-31-Support-for-async-and-iterator-methods) on the the OnMethodBoundary aspect base class via the AllowStateMachine=true property.

I have two related questions:

1. Can this property be set on the OnExceptionAspect or should I change my aspect to extend OnMethodBoundaryAspect instead?
2. What is the difference between the OnExceptionAspect and the OnMethodBoundaryAspect? Should I just always use the OnMethodBoundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. State machines are currently supported only with [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect), so you would need to derive from that class.
2. [OnExceptionAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnExceptionAspect) is more convenient when you need to handle different types of exceptions in different ways. You can specify the exception type to catch in [OnExceptionAspect.GetExceptionType()](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/M_PostSharp_Aspects_OnExceptionAspect_GetExceptionType) method or in [OnExceptionAspectConfiguration.ExceptionType](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/P_PostSharp_Aspects_Configuration_OnExceptionAspectConfiguration_ExceptionType) property.

   [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect) allows you to hook into other method boundaries like entry and exit, however it always catches the base `Exception` type in the catch block.

Comment: Ah okay - thanks for the info! As an aside, it seems surprising that the OnExceptionAspect doesn't support the state machine considering one of the documented uses for the state machine is to appropriately handle exceptions from a different thread. http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/New-in-PostSharp-31-Support-for-async-and-iterator-methods

Comment: You're right, the support for state machines in OnExceptionAspect is planned to be added in one of the upcoming builds of PostSharp.